# Retrieving certain href links from html C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, web-crawler, href

I'm a bit confused on how to extract specific `href` links from an HTML page. There are certainly a good amount of examples, but they seem to cover either gathering an `href` when theres just one on the page, or gathering all the links.

So I currently push the HTML document into a text file using `HttpWebRequest`, `HttpWebResponse`, and `StreamReader`.

Here's my little sample I'm working with, this just downloads the URL of my choice and saves it to a text file.

```
protected void btnURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = txtboxURL.Text;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    //lblResponse.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string urldata = sr.ReadToEnd();

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\test.txt"))
    {
        File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\test.txt");
    }
    File.Create(@"C:\Temp\test.txt").Close();
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\test.txt", urldata);


    sr.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

I can search the entire text file for a `href`, but there are a lot of them on each page, and the ones I'm looking for are sectioned in a `<nav>` tag, and then they are all in `<div>` tags with the same class, sort of like this:

```
<nav class="deptVertNav>
        <div class="acTrigger">
                <a href="*this is what I need to get*" ....
                ....
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="acTrigger">
                <a href="*etc*" ....
                ....
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="acTrigger">
                <a href="*etc*" ....
                ....
                </a>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Essentially I'm trying to create a text crawler/scraper to retrieve links. The current pages I'm working with start at a main page with links down the side on a navigation bar. Those links in the navigation bar are what I want to get to so I may download each of those page's content, and then retrieve the real data I'm looking for. So this is all just one big parse job, and I am terrible at parsing. If I can figure out how to parse this first main page then I will be able to parse the sub pages.

I don't want anyone to just give me the answer, I just want to know what a good method of parsing would be in this situation. IE how do I narrow the parse down to just those tags, and then what would be a good dynamic way to store those links so I can access them later? I hope this makes sense.

EDIT: Well I am now attempting to use HtmlAgilityPack with much confusion. To my knowledge this will retrieve all the nodes that are a `<div class="acTrigger">` that are within the page I load:

```
var div = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='acTrigger']");
```

The next question is how I get inside the `<div>` tag and into the `<a>` tag, and then retrieve the `href` value, and store it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to manually parse the text file, I would recommend placing the HTML in a HtmlDocument control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) or WebBrowser control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).  This allows you to access the elements already parsed.  From there you can easily find all DIV elements with the appropriate class, and then the A element inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#the-5-minute-getting-started-guide) library. Then grab the urls as needed.

```
IWebElement anchorUrl1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//nav[@class='deptVertNav']/div[1]/a[1]"));
string urlText1 = anchorUrl1.Text;
IWebElement anchorUrl2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//nav[@class='deptVertNav']/div[2]/a[1]"));
string urlText2 = anchorUrl2.Text;
```

If all you want to do is click on them, then:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//nav[@class='deptVertNav']/div[1]/a[1]")).Click();
```